# Make an sprite transparent in COCOS2D iPhone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to make a sprite transparent. Let me give an example what i want to implement. Let's say i have one bubble image and one creature image. Now i want to make an illusion that creature in in the bubble. So can i Do this by just setting z index of the sprites and that setting the opacity of the bubble?

Comment: Why haven't you tried it out and see what it looks like? It can't take longer than writing this question.

Comment: i tried that by myself and than posted this question as i was not getting my answer. Than i found my mistake and now that is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see why it wouldn't work, you just have to set the `opacity` and `zOrder` properties of your sprites...

Comment: yeah i did that by setting up opacity and z order.

Answer (score 1):

mySprite.opacity = opaqueFactor;

//  0 –   totally transparent
// 255 –  opaque

This Way , you  can make transparent sprite .